IDE / VM в облаке
Какие есть облачные решения с доступом через браузер с таким функционалом:

Для доступа нужен только браузер, на ПК ничего не устанавливается.
Там можно писать код, устанавливать библиотеки, работать с файловой системой, создавать Postgree базы данных и управлять ими (как-будто я за своим ПК работаю).
Можно разрабатывать интерфейсы (например pyqt для Python).
Вести несколько проектов, каждый в изолированной среде.
Есть возможность развернуть приложение / скрипт (например чтобы простенький личный тг бот крутился 24/7).
Бесплатно или до 500р в месяц и от 10 гб под хранение файлов.
Доступен в России.


VSCode? Что-то вроде https://github.com/coder/code-server

Хотя вообще требование pyqt сужает круг возможных решений до VNC/RDP, ведь этот самый интерфейс pyqt придётся неизбежно куда-то рисовать, а кроме VNC/RDP больше особо и некуда
